# Console app game won't update frames after calling a function inside another function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, console-application

I am a novice coder and i am having problems making my little game update frames everytime I move after selecting and loading the map i want, this started happening after I called the function "contador" (counter) inside the function "sokoban" (yes that crate game) so the contador function could write the steps i've taken to a file called "passos.txt" (steps).

I believe the problem may be in this 2 functions but if needed I will provide the entire code, which isn't absurdly long but its 600 ish lines long.

```
int contador(int m[10][10]) // conta o número de passos
{

    ofstream aqpassos; // cria o stream ofstream para gravação
    aqpassos.open("passos.txt"); // abre o arquivo passos.txt
    int contaPassos = 0; // conta o número de passos
    int x = 0, y = 0; // posição inicial do personagem
    char tecla; // tecla pressionada
    do
    {
        if (_kbhit()) { // se alguma tecla for pressionada
            tecla = _getch(); // pega a tecla pressionada
            if (tecla == 77 || tecla == 75 || tecla == 80 || tecla == 72) { // se a tecla for uma das setas
                contaPassos++; // conta o número de passos
                aqpassos << contaPassos << endl; // grava o número de passos no arquivo passos.txt


            }
        }
    } while (!vitoria(m)); // enquanto o jogo não for vencido, o jogo continua
    //aqpassos.close(); // fecha o arquivo passos.txt
    return contaPassos; // retorna o número de passos

} // it wont write the steps to passos.txt


void sokoban(int m[10][10], int& x, int& y, bool& jogando)
{
    int contaPassos = 0;
    while (!vitoria(m))
    {
        imprimir(m, x, y); // imprime o mapa
        posicaoxy(0, 0); /// posiciona a escrita no console no eixo x,y. A posição 0,0 é a do canto superior esquerdo.
        movimentar(m, x, y); // movimenta o personagem
        contador(m); // conta o número de passos.
    }

    jogando = false;
    system("cls");
    cout << "\nVocê venceu!\nAperte qualquer tecla para retornar ao menu.\n";

    char tecla = _getch();
    system("cls");
    menu(m, x, y, jogando);
}
```

```
void imprimir(int m[10][10], int x, int y) <<prints the map
{


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if (i == x and j == y)
            {
                colorir(10);     /// colorir faz com que a escrita a seguir seja com a cor número 10
                cout << char(2); /// impressão do personagem.
                colorir(7);      /// retorna a cor original após o fim da escrita
            }
            else
            {
                switch (m[i][j])
                {
                case 0:
                    cout << " "; /// impressão do espaço vazio
                    break;

                case 1:
                    colorir(14);
                    // cout<<char(178); ///impressão da parede
                    cout << char(219); /// impressão da parede
                    colorir(7);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    colorir(12);
                    cout << char(219); /// impressão da caixa
                    colorir(7);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    colorir(9);
                    cout << char(4); /// impressão do destino da caixa
                    colorir(7);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    colorir(11);
                    cout << char(219); /// impressão da caixa no destino
                    colorir(7);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
} // fim imprime()

void movimentar(int m[10][10], int& x, int& y) <<moves the player 
{
    bool jogando;
    char tecla;
    if (_kbhit())
    {
        tecla = _getch();
        switch (tecla)
        {
        case 72:
            /// move -> livre
            if (m[x - 1][y] == 0 or m[x - 1][y] == 3)
            {
                x--;
            }
            /// caixa livre -> livre
            else if (m[x - 1][y] == 2 and m[x - 2][y] == 0)
            {
                x--;
                m[x][y] = 0;     /// após o movimento
                m[x - 1][y] = 2; /// a frente do movimento
            }
            /// caixa fim -> livre
            else if (m[x - 1][y] == 4 and m[x - 2][y] == 0)
            {
                x--;
                m[x][y] = 3;     /// após o movimento
                m[x - 1][y] = 2; /// a frente do movimento
            }
            /// caixa livre -> fim
            else if (m[x - 1][y] == 2 and m[x - 2][y] == 3)
            {
                x--;
                m[x][y] = 0;     /// após o movimento
                m[x - 1][y] = 4; /// a frente do movimento
            }
            /// caixa fim -> fim
            else if (m[x - 1][y] == 4 and m[x - 2][y] == 3)
            {
                x--;
                m[x][y] = 3;     /// após o movimento
                m[x - 1][y] = 4; /// a frente do movimento
            }

            break;
        case 80:
        {
            /// move -> livre
            if (m[x + 1][y] == 0 or m[x + 1][y] == 3)
            {
                x++;
            }
            /// caixa livre -> livre
            else if (m[x + 1][y] == 2 and m[x + 2][y] == 0)
            {
                x++;
                m[x][y] = 0;     /// após o movimento
                m[x + 1][y] = 2; /// a frente do movimento
            }
            /// caixa fim -> livre
            else if (m[x + 1][y] == 4 and m[x + 2][y] == 0)
            {
                x++;
                m[x][y] = 3;     /// após o movimento
                m[x + 1][y] = 2; /// a frente do movimento
            }
            /// caixa livre -> fim
            else if (m[x + 1][y] == 2 and m[x + 2][y] == 3)
            {
                x++;
                m[x][y] = 0;     /// após o movimento
                m[x + 1][y] = 4; /// a frente do movimento
            }
            /// caixa fim -> fim
            else if (m[x + 1][y] == 4 and m[x + 2][y] == 3)
            {
                x++;
                m[x][y] = 3;     /// após o movimento
                m[x + 1][y] = 4; /// a frente do movimento
            }
        }
        // x++;
        break;
        case 75:
        {
            /// move -> livre
            if (m[x][y - 1] == 0 or m[x][y - 1] == 3)
            {
                y--;
            }
            /// caixa livre -> livre
            else if (m[x][y - 1] == 2 and m[x][y - 2] == 0)
            {
                y--;
                m[x][y] = 0;     /// após o movimento
                m[x][y - 1] = 2; /// a frente do movimento
            }
            /// caixa fim -> livre
            else if (m[x][y - 1] == 4 and m[x][y - 2] == 0)
            {
                y--;
                m[x][y] = 3;     /// após o movimento
                m[x][y - 1] = 2; /// a frente do movimento
            }
            /// caixa livre -> fim
            else if (m[x][y - 2] == 2 and m[x][y - 2] == 3)
            {
                y--;
                m[x][y] = 0;     /// após o movimento
                m[x][y - 1] = 4; /// a frente do movimento
            }
            /// caixa fim -> fim
            else if (m[x][y - 1] == 4 and m[x][y - 2] == 3)
            {
                y--;
                m[x][y] = 3;     /// após o movimento
                m[x][y - 1] = 4; /// a frente do movimento
            }
        }
        // y--;
        break;
        case 77:
        {
            /// move -> livre
            if (m[x][y + 1] == 0 or m[x][y + 1] == 3)
            {
                y++;
            }
            /// caixa livre -> livre
            else if (m[x][y + 1] == 2 and m[x][y + 2] == 0)
            {
                y++;
                m[x][y] = 0;     /// após o movimento
                m[x][y + 1] = 2; /// a frente do movimento
            }
            /// caixa fim -> livre
            else if (m[x][y + 1] == 4 and m[x][y + 2] == 0)
            {
                y++;
                m[x][y] = 3;     /// após o movimento
                m[x][y + 1] = 2; /// a frente do movimento
            }
            /// caixa livre -> fim
            else if (m[x][y + 1] == 2 and m[x][y + 2] == 3)
            {
                y++;
                m[x][y] = 0;         /// após o movimento
                m[x][y + 1] = 4; /// a frente do movimento
            }
            /// caixa fim -> fim
            else if (m[x][y + 1] == 4 and m[x][y + 2] == 3)
            {
                y++;
                m[x][y] = 3;     /// após o movimento
                m[x][y + 1] = 4; /// a frente do movimento
            }
        }
        // y++;
        break;
        case 27:
        {
            system("cls");
            menu(m, x, y, jogando);
        }
        break;
        }
    }
} // movimento
```

I tried calling the contador function outside the while, doesn't work, tried moving the contador function, doesn't work, tried making the do-while into just a while in the contador function, doesn't work.

Comment: Please add the results of your debugging session to your post.  Post in plain text.

Comment: I don't know how to log a debug session in visual studio 2022, but I found out that the contaPassos is outputting memory trash, a huge random negative number. could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Control is not returning from `contador` so your game cannot continue.

Control's not leaving `contador` because it has an effectively infinite loop:

```
    do
    {
        if (_kbhit()) { // se alguma tecla for pressionada
            tecla = _getch(); // pega a tecla pressionada
            if (tecla == 77 || tecla == 75 || tecla == 80 || tecla == 72) { // se a tecla for uma das setas
                contaPassos++; // conta o número de passos
                aqpassos << contaPassos << endl; // grava o número de passos no arquivo passos.txt


            }
        }
    } while (!vitoria(m));
```

This will keep going until the victory condition `vitoria(m)`, but there's probably no way to get to the victory condition because nothing is happening in this loop that will change the game state. So you are stuck in this loop forever and nothing changes except `contaPassos` gets bigger if you hit a key.

Comment: I guess I could try to make it work without using the victory condition, but then how can I make the counter stop detecting keys after the victory condition is met?

Comment: Because you won't call contador after victory? While you are in the contador function, nothing else is happening. In particular, any key presses you count there are not getting used for game play.